# Add content of ajax form to div ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have this ajax form:

```
@using (@Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Comment", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "comments", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, new{@class = "form-control", id = "exampleFormControlTextarea1", rows = "5", width = "100%", placeholder = "Enter a comment here..." })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

And want to add the whole content after it gets posted to this div:

```
<div class="comments"></div>
```

After searching a bit, I know it should be doable with `UpdateTargetId` and `InsertionMode`, but I still don't get it. Any help would be appreciated!